# Notepad++: How can add the new icon in Notepad++ Toolbar

Tags: c#-4.0, plugins, notepad++

I am trying to add an new plugin in Notepad++. And i want to add an Shortcut icon for that plugin to display inside the Toolbar, like Cut, Copy, Paste Icons.

Can any one guide me how to add an created plugin icon to an Toolbar.

Comment: Can you explain your question a little bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Referencing the Scintilla API documentation should get you pointed in the right direction:

http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#SCI_GETTEXT

Comment: i 've referred  the Scintilla API documentation. it's only for editing in the Scintilla Editor(it mean Notepad++ editing Window). My question is about the NPP toolbar icon creation by c#.net.

Comment: http://appdevonsharepoint.com/adding-custom-toolbar-options-to-notepad/  Here you can find how to add custom icons to the toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware of the "Customize Toolbar" plugin?
It need to be installed to allow you to customize your toolbar.
See e.g.:- http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/customize-toolbar-notepad-plugin-to-add-and-delete-custom-buttons/

Comment: Good answer, however I found the custom tool bar plug in would not install the custom buttons option!  Got to sort that out now.

Comment: I don't see how to add an option of a plugin in there.  All I see is normal commands on the left which can be added.  Am I missing something ?